# Add List output cumulatively

Tags: c#, list

I have a class, I am using list to get  (assigning multiple list entry values in c#).

```
// This will return me more than 1 records.
List<ClassEmpInfo> employeeDetails =GetEmployeeInformation(); 

List<ClassEmployee> empInfo = null; 
foreach (ClassEmployee employee in employeeDetails) 
{
  //This needs to show all the ids belonging to employeeDetails.
  //If there are 3 different employee ids , 
  //the list empInfo should hold the output of all the 3, 
  //but i am getting the last 3rd one alone. 
  //How to cumulatively add 3 different employee ids.

  empInfo = GetEmployeeDetails(Id, EmpId); 
}
```

I am getting the last employee information rather than *all* the employee details in the `empInfo` list.

If the type is string I can do something like:

```
if (strType.Length > 0) 
{  
  strType = strType + returned values; 
} 
else
{  
  strType = strType; 
}
```

How do I add the list values cumulatively?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what your question means.  You need to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
List empInfo = new List<detail_type>(); // whatever type is returned by GetEmployeeDetails
foreach (ClassEmployee employee in employeeDetails)
{
    empInfo.Add(GetEmployeeDetails(id, EmpId));
}
```

It's rather unclear to me, though, if `GetEmployeeDetails` returns a single value or a list of values. If it returns a list of values, then change the line in the loop to:

```
empInfo.AddRange(GetEmployeeDetails(id, EmpId));
```

Answer (score 1):

You add stuff to a list with .Add() this is per definition cumulative.

Comment: Add is specific to single list item, but GetEmployeeDetails() method gives list (as a collection), so i am not able to add List.Add(<list>) on this.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 A list can be an item.